# Dynamic JNLP fetching file from server

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I want to serve up a dynamic JNLP with customized launch `<argument>` tags for a user.

After much hassle, it's almost working.

The user logs into the site, downloads a JNLP which is customized for the user. Java Web Start launches using the downloaded, customized JNLP file.

However, the first a user launches the app, Java Web Start fetches the "master" JNLP file from the server, by using the `href` attribute embedded in the .jnlp file. This doesn't contain the user's custom `<argument>` tag, and things break.

Is there a way to tell JNLP to use the local JNLP file and not fetch it from the server?

Here's my `APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.jnlp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jnlp PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc//DTD JNLP Discriptor 1.5//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/JNLP-1.5.dtd">
<jnlp
        spec="6.0+"
        codebase="http://localhost/jnlp"
        version="1234"
        href="http://localhost/jnlp/app.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>JNLPHelper</title>
        <vendor>Yoyodyne, Inc.</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="true" install="false">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="Yoyodyne, Inc."/>
        </shortcut>
        <association extensions="jnlphelper" mime-type="application-x/jnlphelper"/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
    <resources>
        <java initial-heap-size="32M" max-heap-size="256M" version="1.6+"/>
        <!--<j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>-->
        <jar href="JNLPHelper.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="com.prosc.msi.jnlp.JNLPHelper">
        <argument>*</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

This example file is hosted on my webserver, which during testing is `localhost`. The user downloads a customized JNLP with `<argument>foo</argument>` replacing `<argument>*</argument>`.

I tried removing the `href` attribute entirely from the `<jnlp>` tag. This almost worked, but the application prompts to re-install itself each time, and my desktop icon is removed and re-added.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. How exactly does this work? Why don't you just use a dynamic web page with PHP or something?

Comment: @Robin, I need to send a JNLP to the end-use, and it needs to contain that user's license key, so he doesn't need to manually enter it in the Java Swing application which is launched by the JNLP.

Comment: I understand that, but I still don't understand (a) what you are doing, at all, (b) why you don't use a simple PHP or JSP that *never reveals the master JNLP file* to the web browser. What is it exactly that you are doing?

Comment: Authenticated user logs in to website, and wants to run the Swing application. Clicks a button on the site, which downloads a dynamic JNLP for a signed application. The master JNLP file is used when a user wants to launch the application without any custom args, so it's publicly servable. Are you saying I should omit the href attribute from the <jnlp> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you determining the user? You will probably find it's a session issue or similar where the JNLP href is pointing to what turns out to be an uncustomised .jnlp response.
You might want to change the way you figure who is using the download or allow your app.jnlp URL to take a parameter that confirms who the current user is?

Comment: Yes, the general solution to caching problems like this is "don't allow it to be cached by making the URL different".

Comment: I've edited the question, the issue is not the caching, it's javaws eagerly going and getting a different JNLP from the server, and using that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think that my answer still stands - if the href pointed to a specific URL for that user's JNLP then it would no longer be an issue.